# TFS 2013 Build Cannot convert StringList to String[]

Tags: xaml, tfs, tfsbuild

I added a new parameter and associated Metadata to the default TFS 2013 build definition.

```
<x:Property Name="ProjectFile" Type="InArgument(s:String[])" />

<mtbw:ProcessParameterMetadata Category="#600 Deployment" Description="The csproj file that will be used for deployment" DisplayName="Project to Deploy" Editor="Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Controls.BuildProjectListEditor, Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Controls" ParameterName="ProjectFile" />
```

Note that it is using the same editor as the ProjectsToBuild argument which also has a data type of `string[]`. However I get the following exception:

`Cannot convert value '$/{...}.csproj' of type Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Workflow.Activities.StringList to type System.String[]`.

Any ideas as to what I need to do differently?

Comment: How are you passing the value to this property?

Comment: via the property in the build definition. The editor allows me to select a csproj file from source control....

Answer (score 0):

You should change your property ("ProjectFile") to the type of Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Workflow.Activities.StringList [StringList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.build.workflow.activities.stringlist.aspx).

I used the Reflector to check the type of BuildSettings.ProjectsToBuild and found that it uses the Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Workflow.Activities.StringList [StringList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.build.workflow.activities.stringlist.aspx) type.

[image]